# executing a pi command from a C program

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I installed the MJPG-Streamer and i want to run this from a C program.
I start the MJPG-Streamer entering the following code in the pi terminal:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i "input_file.so -f /tmp/stream -n pic.jpg" -o "output_http.so -w /usr/local/www"
```

I want to run mjpg streamer from a C program, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `system()` function.

Comment: With `system("LD_LIBRARY_PATH ...")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `system()` function inside stdlib header.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure `system()` will work fine, but I always feel a bit uncomfortable about using it in situations like the one described -- particularly in an embedded application, where the memory and CPU overhead of spawning another shell might be undesirable. In addition, you don't get a process ID from `system()`, which you might need to interact with the child process later.

Although it's a bit more work, I think it's more elegant to use `fork()` followed by (for example) `execle()`. You'll need an `exec` variant that takes an environment argument, because you'll need to ensure that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set in the new process. It's a bit of a faff, but you could maybe use the `envz_xxx` family of functions to create the new process environment from the parent environment, rather than building the environment from scratch.

To be honest, I'd be tempted to use `system()` myself, but doing it the "hard" way might offer more flexibility in the long run, as well as being slightly faster and more memory-efficient.